# Getting nth/last value inside a hash of hashes

Tags: perl, hashmap, hashtable

I'm trying to make a hash of hashes to uniquely identify the number that only comes under one set of levels. The hash structure looks something like this:

```
my %gh = {
      'Test1' => {
                   'level1a' => {
                           'level2b' => {
                                   'level3a' => {
                                           'level4a' => {
                                                   'level5' => '63'
                                                 }
                                         }
                                 }
                         }
               }
      };
```

What is the simplest way to traverse the hash so I can get the value 63?

I have been using:

```
my $x = '';
foreach my $l0 (%gh){
          foreach my $l1 (%{$l0}){
           foreach my $l2 (%$l1){
            foreach my $l3 (%{$l2}){
             foreach my $l4 (%$l3){
              foreach my $l5 (%{$l4}){
               $x = $l5;
              }
             }
            }
           }
          }
         }
```

This process seems to be working fine, but I was just looking for something simpler and shorter.

Comment: Your example will not do what you expect. Also, your above code will not work because you are assigning a hashref to a hash.

Comment: How do you want to extract value, what do you know in advance about hash structure?

Comment: The question only makes sense if each hash only has one key, in which case the data structure makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a reference to a hash instead, here is one way:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $gh = {
      'Test1' => {
                   'level1a' => {
                           'level2b' => {
                                   'level3a' => {
                                           'level4a' => {
                                                   'level5' => '63'
                                                 }
                                         }
                                 }
                         }
               }
      };           

print $gh->{Test1}{level1a}{level2b}{level3a}{level4a}{level5}, "\n";
```

See also: [perldoc perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) and [Data::Diver](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3a%3aDiver)

Answer (score 2):

This will work in your case (only hashes, and plain scalar value at the end)

```
sub hval {
  my ($h) = @_;
  return map { ref() ? hval($_) : $_ } values %$h;
}

my $gh = {
      'Test1' => {
                   'level1a' => {
                           'level2b' => {
                                   'level3a' => {
                                           'level4a' => {
                                                   'level5' => '63'
                                                 }
                                         }
                                 }
                         }
               }
};     

my ($x) = hval($gh);
```